# Insert entities simultaneously having one to one in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities with a one-to-one relationship, I am trying to save the two entities simultaneously without doing context.SaveChanges between the first entity and the second but i have INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint dbo.HotelImages', column 'Id'.
This is my code:

```
var hotelImage = new HotelImageEntity
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    IdHotel = entity.Id,
    GalleryId = galleryId,
    IdImageType = idImageType
});

await _context.HotelsImages.Add(hotelImage);

var hotelMultimediaHighlighted = new HotelMultimediaHighlighted
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    IdHotel = entity.Id,
    IdHotelImage = hotelImage.Id,
    Order = 1
});

await _context.HotelMultimediaHighlighteds.Add(hotelMultimediaHighlighted);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And this is entity mapping

```
public class HotelMultimediaHighlightMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<HotelMultimediaHighlightedEntity>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<HotelMultimediaHighlightedEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(hm => hm.Id);

            builder.HasOne(hm => hm.Hotel)
                .WithMany(h => h.HotelMultimediaHighlighteds)
                .HasForeignKey(hm => hm.IdHotel);

            builder.HasOne(hm => hm.HotelVideo)
                .WithOne(hv => hv.HotelMultimediaHighlight)
                .HasForeignKey<HotelMultimediaHighlightedEntity>(hm => hm.IdHotelVideo);

            builder.HasOne(hm => hm.HotelImage)
                .WithOne(hg => hg.HotelMultimediaHighlightEntity)
                .HasForeignKey<HotelMultimediaHighlightedEntity>(hm => hm.IdHotelImage);

            builder.ToTable("HotelMultimediaHighlighted");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Are you aware that _true_ `1:1` relationships are impossible without DB support for deferred-constraints?

Comment: `Id = Guid.NewGuid(),` <-- ugh. [Don't use normal GUIDs for primary-keys because it will thrash your PK index](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/11/22/uuids-are-popular-but-bad-for-performance-lets-discuss/) - also, why are you even doing this in application-code instead of using a DB-generated PK?

Comment: @Dai SQL Server, because if i use a DB generated PK how can i know the id to use it in HotelMultimediaHighlighted?

Comment: [EF+EFCore fully supports database-generated columns, including `IDENTITY` columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations). The `DbContext` keeps track of entity objects via object-reference-identity (that's what your navigation properties are for). (Did you seriously believe EF didn't support such a fundamental feature?)

Answer (score 0):

You can just attach them together by assigning the `HotelMultimediaHighlightedEntity` directly to the `HotelImage` and the foreign will be key in automatically.

```
HotelImageEntity hotelImage = new HotelImageEntity
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    IdHotel = entity.Id,
    GalleryId = galleryId,
    IdImageType = idImageType,
    HotelMultimediaHighlightEntity = new HotelMultimediaHighlightEntity()
   {
       Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
       IdHotel = entity.Id,
       Order = 1
   }
};

await _context.HotelsImages.Add(hotelImage);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Edit : Edit to give better clarification and idea.

Comment: Okk, sorry for that. What I mean is to attach them together. Thanks